# Is $a\in A$ and $\{a\}\subset A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set $A=\{\{a,b\},\{c\},\{d,e,f\}\}$. Does it mean that $a\in A$ and $\{a\}\subset A$?

Since $\{a\}\subset \{a,b\}$ and $\{a,b\}\subset A$ can we conclude that $\{a\}\subset A$ and thus $a\in A$? (If these two statements are even related in such way)

On the other hand wouldn't this be in contradiction with the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) $P(A)$, since it is a set of all subsets of $A$, but it doesn't include the set $\{a\}$?

Comment: {a, b} ⊂ A is not true. Everything else in the second paragraph is true.

Comment: $a\in A$ and $\{a\}\subseteq A$ mean the same thing. Whether or not it's true depends on whether $a$ is one of the three elements of $A$, i.e. whether $a=\{a,b\},$ $a=\{c\}$ or $a=\{d,e,f\}.$ Without further assumptions about the nature of $a,b,c,d,e,f$ it's impossible to determine whether the latter two of these are true (the former can be ruled out if we're assuming the axiom of regularity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  $a \in A$ means $A$ is a **member** of the set $A$.  You listed the members of $A$: $\{a,b\}$, $\{c\}$ and $\{d, e, f\}$.  $\{a,b\}$ is a member of $A$, not a subset of $A$, i.e. it is not true that $\{a,b\} \subset A$.

Comment: $\{\{a,b\}\}$ is?

Comment: Yes, $\{\{a,b\}\} \subset A$.